# How to detect & change element in a list?

Tags: python

I have a list of numbers with decimals, there is a chance that the list turns out as below

```
my_list = [ '0.2319', '0.4216' , '0.2295', '0.4150' , '2271', '0.2319' , '02340', '04126']
```

expected output is as below :

```
my_list = [ '0.2319', '0.4216' , '0.2295', '0.4150' , '0.2271', '0.2319' , '0.2340', '0.4126']
```

Any idea how to do this ?

Thank you

---

Update :
Here is my approach to detect

```
my_list = [ '0.2319', '0.4216' , '0.2295', '0.4150' , '2271', '0.2319' , '02340', '04126']
list_2 = ['0.' in str(x) for x in my_list]
print(list_2)
```

My output is as below :

```
[True,True,True,True,False,True,True,False]
```

i am trying to put for loop and if statement to detect and ammend it to my expected output

---

Update 2
Here is my approach to detect & ammend the data

```
my_list = ['0.2319' , '0.4126' , '0.2295','0.4150','2271','0.2319','0.2340','04126']

fixed_list = []

for x in my_list:
    if not x.startswith('0.') :
        x= "0." + x.lstrip('0')
        fixed_list.append(x)
        
print( fixed_list)
```

and my output is

```
['0.2271', '0.4126']
```

how do i change to this

````
fixed_list = [ '0.2319', '0.4216' , '0.2295', '0.4150' , '0.2271', '0.2319' , '0.2340', '0.4126']```
````

Comment: Please do add your tried code in your question. which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: Hi there, i had made an update on my approach, any idea i can use if statement to do the ammend ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this a couple of ways. He's one:

```py
my_list = ['0.2319', '0.4216' , '0.2295', '0.4150' , '2271', '0.2319' , '02340', '4126']
my_list2 = ['0.2319', '0.4216' , '0.2295', '0.4150' , '0.2271', '0.2319' , '0.2340', '0.4126']

fixed_list = []
for number in my_list:
    if not number.startswith('0.'):
        number = "0." + number.lstrip('0')
    
    fixed_list.append(number)

print(fixed_list == my_list2)
```

Output:

```
True
```

If each number (which is actually of type `str`) does not start with `0.`, then all the leading `0`s are stripped from it, and `0.` is prepended to it.

---

Here is another way, using regex:

```py
import re

my_list = ['0.2319', '0.4216' , '0.2295', '0.4150' , '2271', '0.2319' , '02340', '4126']
my_list2 = ['0.2319', '0.4216' , '0.2295', '0.4150' , '0.2271', '0.2319' , '0.2340', '0.4126']

fixed_list = [re.sub("^0*(?=[1-9])", "0.", number) for number in my_list]

print(fixed_list == my_list2)
```

Output:

```
True
```

If the string starts with 0 or more of `0`s and is followed a non-zero digit, then the `0`s are substituted with `0.`.

Have a play around with it here - https://regex101.com/r/E0AiQ7/1

Comment: Yes, this actually work, but if i need the fixed value to be inside the ```fixed_list``` with the same sequence, how do i approach this ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you please elaborate or give an example?

Comment: hi there, i made an update with your approach, but my output is ```['0.2271', '0.4126']``` how to i get same output as ```my_list2```

Comment: You need to change the indentation of `fixed_list.append(x)` so it is outside the `if` statement. At the moment, the number is only appended if it starts with `0.`, but you want to append it all the time. Remove 4 spaces.

Comment: got it , beginners mistake, thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

You're so close, you're just not copying across the values that weren't erroneous.

Try dedenting the append:

```
my_list = ['0.2319', '0.4126', '0.2295', '0.4150', '2271', '0.2319', '0.2340', '04126']

fixed_list = []

for x in my_list:
    if not x.startswith('0.'):
        x = f'0.{x.lstrip("0")}'
    fixed_list.append(x)

print(fixed_list)
```

You can also use list comprehension:

```
my_list = ['0.2319', '0.4126', '0.2295', '0.4150', '2271', '0.2319', '0.2340', '04126']

fixed_list = [x if x.startswith('0.')
              else f'0.{x.lstrip("0")}'
              for x in my_list]

print(fixed_list)
```

Comment: Thanks , this is another approach for me to try out